# Prove that $\sum r_i$ is a multiple of $n$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $0<r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n<n$ where all the numbers in discussion are positive integers. Prove that we can choose some of these numbers, such that $\sum r_i$ is a multiple of $n$.

OK let me phrase this problem in a more rigorous way: Let R be a set of $n$ positive integers, all of which strictly less than $n$ (So repeat is allowed here. Actually by pigeon hole, there exist at least 2 numbers repeated). Prove that there exist a non empty subset of R, call it S, such that $\sum r_i\in S$ is a multiple of $n$. You cannot set these $r_i$ to numbers you want.

This problem looks basic, and there might be answers already. But I cannot find a proper way to simply address this problem in search engine.

Yes all the things mentioned here are integers. I do not find this trivial for a rigorous proof.

Thanks for pointing out that in set notation repeated element is not allow. I am not sure when we want to talk about something that repeatition is allowed, what kind of notation we should use. But I think just saying set with repeated elements should be enough to make myself clear.

Comment: The problem says that we can CHOOSE these numbers so certainly we can choose them to be integers.

Comment: My interpretation is that $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ are fixed, and to show that you can choose some nonempty subset of $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_n$ (or technically nonempty sub-multiset I guess, in case there are some repeats) whose sum is a multiple of $n$.

Comment: Umm, in the latest edit, it's impossible to have a set $R$ of $n$ distinct positive integers which are all strictly less than $n$ -- so technically, the answer would be that the statement is vacuously true.

Comment: Does it work for $\{2, 2, 2\}$?

Comment: Maybe another way to state what we're saying is: given integers $r_1, \ldots, r_n$, there exists a nonempty subset $S \subseteq \{ 1, 2 \ldots, n \}$ such that $\sum_{i\in S} r_i$ is a multiple of $n$.  (And then, if you want, you can restrict all $r_i$ to be strictly positive and less than $n$; but that doesn't significantly change the problem.)

Comment: @Aruralreader Yes, then $n=3$ and $2+2+2$ is a multiple of 3.

Comment: yes, 2+2+2=6 is multiple of 3

Comment: Thanks @DanielSchepler, I ought to have been a bit better about reading the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order the elements arbitrarily, say $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_n$. Let $R_a=\sum_{i=1}^a r_i$ for all $a$ where $1\leq a\leq n$. If any $R_a$ is congruent to $0\text{ (mod }n)$, then you have such a subset. Otherwise, we assume that each $R_a$ is congruent to some $x_a\text{ (mod } n)$ where $x_a\in\{1,2,\ldots, n-1\}$. By the pidgeonhole principle, we must have distinct $i$ and $j$ such that $x_i=x_j$. Without loss of generality, assume $i>j$. Then $$R_i-R_j=r_{j+1}+r_{j+2}+\cdots +r_i\equiv 0\text{ (mod }n)$$ so the claim holds.

Comment: Or similarly, you include $R_0 = 0$ and observe that now you're looking at $n+1$ numbers $R_0, R_1, \ldots, R_n$ in $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ so there must be a repeat; and then you don't need to consider the case $R_a \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ separately.

Comment: This one is amazing. Let me taste this a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R = \{r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n \}$ where all elements are positive integers $<n$. Consider the set $S = \{n-r_i,r_i,n-r_j,r_j \} \subset R$. The sum of the elements in $S$ is $2n$. Still some details to work out if $n-r_i=r_i$.